# Why the tabs are not in the bottom in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, bottomnavigationview, tabbedpage

Fellow Developers,

I'm developing an app with Xamarin.Forms and I am using the latest version 3.1, which as far as I know it supports Bottom Tabs in Android. This is my code:

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
    android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#666666"
    android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="Black"
    BarBackgroundColor="#2196F3"
    BarTextColor="White"></TabbedPage>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BottomTabsExample
{
    public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new History());
            navigationPage.Icon = "ic_history.png";
            navigationPage.Title = "History";

            var navigationPage2 = new NavigationPage(new History());
            navigationPage2.Icon = "ic_earth.png";
            navigationPage2.Title = "Earth";
            Children.Add(navigationPage);
            Children.Add(navigationPage2);
        }
    }
}
```

However, they are always display in the upper part as the following image:

[image: android oreo]

The previous image uses Android Oreo 8.1 (I also tested the version 7.1 and I had the same result). I got partial examples from these blogs:

https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-official-bottom-navigation-bottom-tabs-on-android/

https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-3-1-improvments/

Also, the version of .NET Standard and Xamarin.Forms:

[image: versions]

Have any of you experienced it before? Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the tabs are not in the bottom in Xamarin Forms?

I found that your were missing `InitializeComponent()` in your `MainPage`, that's why the issue happens.

The `InitializeComponent()` method will load the `XAML` content, when you delete this method, your `XAML` content will be ignored.

## Solution:

Set Bottom Tabs in C# code behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;

On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
```

Comment: Hi, when I add the C# I get an issue. I'll share it later because I tried it before

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete, is there any updates about this issue?